# How is signal transmitted when pressing ctrl+c

Tags: linux-kernel, interrupt-handling

As I know, each process running in bash is the child process of that bash.
For example, if I run an infinite loop in bash, the OS will fork bash and create a new child process to run that loop.
Then if I press ctrl+c, the child process would be killed.
Now I am confused about who the sender of the signal is , since I think the parent bash process is waiting now.
Is it the child process itself or the kernel? As far as I know, keyboard activities can cause hard interuptions,which can only be handled by kernel, or does the child process turn to kernel state when the key is pressed?

Comment: I had an answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9853921/installing-sigtstp-foreground-process/9854819#9854819

Answer (score 0):

Your understanding is incorrect.

It's not "the os forking bash", it is be bash forking itself, except for the trivial case you had in mind there is no fork in the first place.

Either way, the tty driver "sends" the signal to the foreground process (here: bash), and said process can catch it and act on it, e.g. break the loop.

Comment: bash and the forked loop are two processes,but who is now the fg you have said?

Comment: by saying "os forks the bash", I just mean fork is a system call, can you recommend me some articles or books to understand the who details here?

Comment: I said for the simple while true; do echo crap; done there is no forking done in the first place, which you can easily verify if you run the bash process under strace. Unfortunately I don't have a good resource for you, you likely want Advanced Programming in the UNIX Environment by Stevens.

Comment: For starters, have a look at [Process group - Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_group).